# is it possible to convert English to Chinese using angular translate without having translation table in Chinese?

Tags: angularjs, multilingual, angular-translate, language-translation

var translations = {
              HEADLINE: 'What an awesome module!',
              PARAGRAPH: 'Srsly!',
              NAMESPACE: {
                PARAGRAPH: 'And it comes with awesome features!'
              }
            };

```
      $translateProvider
        .translations('en', translations)
        .preferredLanguage('en');
```

Comment: Is there any method which converts english to chinese without having two translation table?

Comment: No. Despite its name, angular-translate doesn't translate anything. All it does is display messages associated to keys. Its goal is to internationalize the app, not to automatically translate from one language to another.

Comment: then how can I get the text translated automatically? because there is lot of text which is unorganised and it should be displayed in various languages. thanks in advance!

Comment: Use google translate, or better: hire a real translator. Automatic translation will be awful. Especially if what you translate isn't even correct English (Srsly, for example)